# PHP multidimensional array duplicate

Tags: php, arrays

I've looked all over the web for a reason why I can't remove duplicates from my array.
I am aware of array_unique but it's not working.

I have an array called $links which is populated from the links found in html source code

If i then echo out

```
$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $html, $links, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach($links as $link) {
        echo($link[2]."<br />"); // $link[2] = address, $link[3] = text
    }
}
```

it outputs each link to a new line perfectly, however there are duplicates

$link[2] is the only dimension of the array i am interested in, and i cannot remove its duplicates, can anyone help?

This is what is echoed out, for example

```
/
/register
/forgotpass
/
/news
/news
/news/submit_article
#
/recruiters/companies
/recruiters/headhunters
/jobs
/jobs
/jobs/submit_job
/about
/jobs
/jobs/submit_job
/resume
/register
/fullmap
```

I would hope to see

```
/
/register
/forgotpass
/news
/news/submit_article
#
/recruiters/companies
/recruiters/headhunters
/jobs
/about
/jobs/submit_job
/resume
/fullmap
```

FIXED BY JON - ANSWER:

```
$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $html, $links, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    $unique_links = array_unique(array_map(function($item) { return $item[2]; }, $links));
    foreach($unique_links as $link) {
        echo($link."<br />");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample for `$html` that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: Also, some more detail on what is your expected output? Just an array of unique URIs? Do you also need the text? Which piece of text do you want back if there are two links with the same URI but diffent text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply extract the "row" you are interested in from the array and call `array_unique` on that:

```
$unique_links = array_unique(array_map(function($item) { return $item[2]; }, $links));
```

This code will only run on PHP >= 5.3 due to the lambda syntax, but you can also use `create_function` for earlier PHP versions.

**[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IdP302)**.

Comment: Incredible, works perfectly, thanks SO much - updating question with example answer, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is filter duplicate entries, you can do so by loading them into an array and using in_array() to determine if they're already there.

```
$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $html, $links, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
  $filter_links = array();
  foreach ($links as $link) {
    if (!in_array($filter_links)) {
      $filter_links[] = $link[2];
      echo $link[2]."<br />";
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: But the answer above is a better solution :)